# underline costum entry again

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a problem, that I'm not able to solve. Maybe you can  help me. I want to make a flexible underline for an entry in xamarin forms. When I set the BackgroundColor of my customEntry to transparent the underline disappears but I'm not able to "bring" it back to appear. I've tried a few things, like set new bounds, which didn't work for just the bottom or set an new BackgroundColor. Google couldn't help me either.
Do you have an idea, what could solve that issue?

Thank you

My PCL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MultiBaseCS_Mobile
{
    public class CustomEntryCell : Entry
    {

        public static readonly  BindableProperty HasUnderlineProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HasUnderline), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomEntryCell), true);

        public CustomEntryCell()
        {
        }

        public bool HasUnderline
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasUnderlineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HasUnderlineProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

my customRenderer

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MultiBaseCS_Mobile;
using MultiBaseCS_Mobile.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntryCell), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace MultiBaseCS_Mobile.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var entry = (CustomEntryCell)Element;

            if (entry != null)
            {
                if (!entry.HasUnderline)
                {
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                }

            }
        }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            var entry = (CustomEntryCell)Element;

            if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntryCell.HasUnderlineProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (!entry.HasUnderline)
                {
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Underline should appear
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you try to "bring" it back to appear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can try

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MultiBaseCS_Mobile;
using MultiBaseCS_Mobile.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntryCell), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace MultiBaseCS_Mobile.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        InsetDrawable originalBackgroundDrawable = null;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            originalBackgroundDrawable = Control.Background as InsetDrawable;

            var entry = (CustomEntryCell)Element;    
            if (entry != null)
            {
                if (!entry.HasUnderline)
                {
                    Control.SetBackground(null);
                }

            }
        }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var entry = (CustomEntryCell)Element;    
            if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntryCell.HasUnderlineProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (!entry.HasUnderline)
                {
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Underline should appear
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(originalBackgroundDrawable);
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```